# Re-login to a different account with gmailr

Tags: r, gmail, gmail-api

I am using the `gmailr` package in R.

If I initially want to run a function where I specify `userid = "me"`, then R will redirect me to chrome to ask me to login.

However, I now want to change the account I am using now.

For example:

When I run the below code initially, a pop-up in chrome will appear to have me login.

```
library(gmailr)
raw_folder_outputs<-labels(user_id = "me")
```

[image]

After that, the account I am using is set.

How do I change the account I am using in gmailr so that when I run `user_id = "me"` it will be redirected to another account?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

At the beginning of the code you need to do this:

```
gmailr::clear_token()
gmailr::gmail_auth()
```